# React Native remove item from 1 array and set is in another array

Tags: arrays, react-native, setstate

What I am doing is trying to remove an item from array1 and
add it to array2. see code below:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.state.Array1.length; i++){

      if(this.state.Array1[i].Id === item.Id){

        var copiedArray1 = [...this.state.Array1];
        copiedArray1.splice(i, 1);
        var copiedArray2= [item, ...this.state.Array2]


        this.setState({
          Array1: copiedArray1,
          Array2: copiedArray2
        });


        console.log('state', this.state)
      }

  }
```

the first time it doesn`t add the item to the array stays empty
Seconde time is add is to the array but it doesnt change the view.

Someone know how to fix this?

Comment: You will not be able to see new state right after the setState function, because setState is async, to see new state when it is refreshed add callback function inside of setState function ->  `this.setState({
          Array1: copiedArray1,
          Array2: copiedArray2
        }, () => console.log('state', this.state));`

Answer (score 0):

1. you are setting your state inside the for loop
2. also iterating the and creating yout copy arrays inside the for loop as well

this casuses creation of new arrays and setting state each time the function runs in the for loop. Move setstates and the array declerations outside of the for loop then it will work

Comment: can you share how did you change it?

Comment: var Array1 = [...this.state.Array1];
      var Array2 = [...this.state.Array2];

      for(var i = 0; i < this.state.Array1.length; i++){

          if(this.state.Array1[i].Id === item.Id){

            Array1.splice(i, 1);
            Array2= [incident, ...this.state.inprogressIncidents]




          }

      }

      

      this.setState({
        Array1: Array1,
        Array2: Array2
      });

Comment: you should change to ```this.state.Array1.length - 1``` but other than that this should work. It might worth to check other parts of your code and incoming parameters

Comment: why the - 1? you mean like this for(var i = 0; i < this.state.Array1.length - 1; i++)

Comment: yes, i know its unrelated but it just bothered me :), as I said the function looks okay

Answer (score 0):

```
    const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
    let array2 = [];
    const id =4

    const found = array1.filter(item=> item === id);
    if(found && found[0]) {
      array2 = [...array2, found[0]]
    }
   this.setState({
      array2 
    })
```

es6 clean code. modify it according to your needs (Also do not setState on loop)

Answer (score 0):

I made a little sample, you can run it and click on the items of the left array (Array1) and transfer it to the second one.

This is the crucial part of code doing the transfer of items and updating state:

```
const foundItem = this.state.Array1.find(arrayItem => arrayItem.Id === item.Id);
if (foundItem) {
  const copiedArray1 = this.state.Array1.filter(fItem => fItem.Id !== item.Id);
  const copiedArray2= [ foundItem, ...this.state.Array2];

  this.setState({
    Array1: copiedArray1,
    Array2: copiedArray2
  }, () => console.log('state', this.state));
}
```

I would use it instead of the for loop because I don't like the idea of removing items from the same array you are iterating through. Also, I would suggest using setState method outside of the for loop, it will be called asynchronously.

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Array1: [ {Id: 1}, {Id: 11}, {Id: 12}, {Id: 13}, {Id: 14}, {Id: 15} ],
    Array2: [ {Id: 3} ]
  };
  
  handleClick = (item) => {
    const foundItem = this.state.Array1.find(arrayItem => arrayItem.Id === item.Id);
    if (foundItem) {
      const copiedArray1 = this.state.Array1.filter(fItem => fItem.Id !== item.Id);
      const copiedArray2= [ foundItem, ...this.state.Array2];
    
      this.setState({
        Array1: copiedArray1,
        Array2: copiedArray2
      }, () => console.log('state', this.state));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{display: 'flex' }}>
        <h1>Array1</h1>
        <ul style={{ marginRight: 50 }}>
        {this.state.Array1.map(item => <li key={`A1-${item.Id}`} onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>{item.Id}</li>)}
        </ul>

        <h1>Array2</h1>
        <ul>
        {this.state.Array2.map(item => <li key={`A2-${item.Id}`} onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>{item.Id}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```